# General:munfl error problem

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I have the following function, that is the result of The integration between x and some upper limit of a positive function, thus should be positive

$f(x,vE) = \frac{e^{-1140.09 x} \left(e^{67945.5 \text{vE}^2} \theta (\text{1.859514170346336$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}-x)
   \left(e^{1140.09 x} \left(-\text{3.3591048468065713$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-37}
   \text{vE}^8+\text{1.2371349122599874$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} x^8+\text{4.6259292692714846$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-18} x^7-\text{5.720218174055417$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} x^6-\text{3.830505707541381$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-19} x^5-\text{6.875632678803749$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-22} x^4-\text{2.592004365421134$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25} x^3+\text{1.1383704954727588$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-27} x^2-\text{1.0946897704176435$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} x+\text{2.0355911402247853$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}\right)+\text{1.1896770509204967$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} x^5-\text{8.30796052725145$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} x^4+\text{1.4721183020268512$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} x^3-\text{7.569314750088174$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12} x^2+\text{1.0946949062266079$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} x-\text{2.0355980730229598$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}\right)+e^{67945.5 \text{vE}^2}
   \left(-\text{1.1896770509204967$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} x^5+\text{8.30796052725145$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}
   x^4-\text{1.4721183020268512$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} x^3+\text{7.569314750088174$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12}
   x^2-\text{1.0946949062266079$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} x+\text{2.0355980730229598$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}\right)+e^{67945.5 \text{vE}^2+1140.09 x} \left(\text{vE}^{16} (1.
   x-\text{1.8595141703463354$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9})+\text{vE}^{14} (\text{2.0083576467270298$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14}-0.0000108004 x)+\text{vE}^{12} (\text{2.663670413232032$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}
   x-\text{4.953132878537244$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15})+\text{vE}^{10} (\text{5.166994397269747$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} x-\text{9.608099299823222$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-19})+\text{vE}^8
   (\text{2.571855800860126$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21}-\text{1.383079431108135$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12}
   x)+\text{vE}^6 (\text{1.7552515711539956$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25}-\text{9.439301937812491$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17} x)+\text{vE}^4 (\text{1.4313862961095703$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21}
   x-\text{2.6616831008553027$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-30})+\text{vE}^2 (\text{2.9153325110971034$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-34}-\text{1.5677925759254207$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25} x)-\text{1.2371349122599874$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} x^8-\text{4.6259292692714846$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-18} x^7+\text{5.720218174055417$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} x^6+\text{3.830505707541381$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-19} x^5+\text{6.875632678803749$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-22} x^4+\text{2.592004365421134$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25} x^3-\text{1.1383704954727588$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-27} x^2+\text{1.2253923290809874$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-30} x-\text{1.6264357714319357$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-39}\right)+e^{33972.8 \text{vE}^2+1140.09 x} \left(\text{vE}^8 (0.00937982
   x-\text{1.744191593358305$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-11})+\text{vE}^6 (\text{4.087595291558347$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-13}-0.000219821 x)+\text{vE}^4 (\text{1.3071488339510708$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}
   x-\text{2.430661779483706$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15})+\text{vE}^2 (\text{4.1941725957388944$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-19}-\text{2.255520642231904$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} x)-\text{6.639200573944934$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15} x+\text{1.2345687547022132$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}\right)+(\text{1.7586098278121368$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} x-\text{3.270159894926998$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23}) e^{33972.8 \text{vE}^2+1140.09 x}\right)
   \theta \left(29.7983 \text{vE}^2-x+\text{1.859514170346336$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}\right)}{\left(e^{33972.8
   \text{vE}^2} \left(0.00937982 \text{vE}^8-0.000219821 \text{vE}^6+\text{1.3071488339510708$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}
   \text{vE}^4-\text{2.2555206422319046$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} \text{vE}^2-\text{6.639200573944936$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15}\right)+\text{1.758609827812137$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} e^{33972.8 \text{vE}^2}+e^{67945.5
   \text{vE}^2} \left(1. \text{vE}^{16}-0.0000108004 \text{vE}^{14}+\text{2.6636704132320325$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}
   \text{vE}^{12}+\text{5.166994397269748$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} \text{vE}^{10}-\text{1.3830794311081354$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12} \text{vE}^8-\text{9.439301937812495$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17}
   \text{vE}^6+\text{1.4313862961095709$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-21} \text{vE}^4-\text{1.567792575925421$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25} \text{vE}^2-\text{1.0946897704176435$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14}\right)\right)
   (x-\text{1.859514170346336$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9})}$

I am trying to get values of this function for vE up to 0.141421, however I start getting problems at vE=0.10. This is probably due to underflow errors. I have tried wrapping the function inside a SetPrecision, as well as using

$f[SetPrecision[x,$MachienPrecision],SetPrecision[vE,$MachienPrecision]]$

with no luck. I am afraid that the problem is the precision of the numeric coefficients of the function, that need to be set to arbitrary precision to fix the underflow.

Any suggestion on how to fix this problem without having to rewrite the function (it`s generated automatically by my program, chaging the part that generates it would be cubersome)

EDIT: Inputform expression

```
((E^(33972.7745398073*vE^2 + 1140.0906489396789*x)*(1.2345687547022132*^-23 + 
     vE^6*(4.087595291558347*^-13 - 0.00021982060458281043*x) + 
     vE^2*(4.1941725957388944*^-19 - 2.255520642231904*^-10*x) + 
     vE^4*(-2.430661779483706*^-15 + 1.3071488339510708*^-6*x) + vE^8*(-1.744191593358305*^-11 + 0.00937982415607754*x) - 
     6.639200573944934*^-15*x) + E^(33972.774539807324*vE^2 + 1140.0906489396789*x)*
    (-3.270159894926998*^-23 + 1.7586098278121368*^-14*x) + E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*
    (2.0355980730229598*^-23 - 1.0946949062266079*^-14*x + 7.569314750088174*^-12*x^2 - 1.4721183020268512*^-9*x^3 + 
     8.30796052725145*^-9*x^4 - 1.1896770509204967*^-8*x^5) + E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2 + 1140.0906489396789*x)*
    (-1.6264357714319357*^-39 + vE^14*(2.0083576467270298*^-14 - 0.000010800442818636717*x) + 
     vE^8*(2.571855800860126*^-21 - 1.383079431108135*^-12*x) + 
     vE^6*(1.7552515711539956*^-25 - 9.439301937812491*^-17*x) + 
     vE^2*(2.9153325110971034*^-34 - 1.5677925759254207*^-25*x) + 
     vE^4*(-2.6616831008553027*^-30 + 1.4313862961095703*^-21*x) + 
     vE^10*(-9.608099299823222*^-19 + 5.166994397269747*^-10*x) + 
     vE^12*(-4.953132878537244*^-15 + 2.663670413232032*^-6*x) + vE^16*(-1.8595141703463354*^-9 + 0.9999999999999998*x) + 
     1.2253923290809874*^-30*x - 1.1383704954727588*^-27*x^2 + 2.592004365421134*^-25*x^3 + 6.875632678803749*^-22*x^4 + 
     3.830505707541381*^-19*x^5 + 5.720218174055417*^-21*x^6 - 4.6259292692714846*^-18*x^7 - 
     1.2371349122599874*^-16*x^8) + E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*(-2.0355980730229598*^-23 + 1.0946949062266079*^-14*x - 
     7.569314750088174*^-12*x^2 + 1.4721183020268512*^-9*x^3 - 8.30796052725145*^-9*x^4 + 1.1896770509204967*^-8*x^5 + 
     E^(1140.0906489396789*x)*(2.0355911402247853*^-23 - 3.3591048468065713*^-37*vE^8 - 1.0946897704176435*^-14*x + 
       1.1383704954727588*^-27*x^2 - 2.592004365421134*^-25*x^3 - 6.875632678803749*^-22*x^4 - 
       3.830505707541381*^-19*x^5 - 5.720218174055417*^-21*x^6 + 4.6259292692714846*^-18*x^7 + 
       1.2371349122599874*^-16*x^8))*HeavisideTheta[1.859514170346336*^-9 - x])*
  HeavisideTheta[1.859514170346336*^-9 + 29.79830996018*vE^2 - x])/
 (E^(1140.0906489396789*x)*(1.758609827812137*^-14*E^(33972.774539807324*vE^2) + 
   E^(33972.7745398073*vE^2)*(-6.639200573944936*^-15 - 2.2555206422319046*^-10*vE^2 + 1.3071488339510708*^-6*vE^4 - 
     0.00021982060458281048*vE^6 + 0.009379824156077542*vE^8) + E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*
    (-1.0946897704176435*^-14 - 1.567792575925421*^-25*vE^2 + 1.4313862961095709*^-21*vE^4 - 
     9.439301937812495*^-17*vE^6 - 1.3830794311081354*^-12*vE^8 + 5.166994397269748*^-10*vE^10 + 
     2.6636704132320325*^-6*vE^12 - 0.000010800442818636719*vE^14 + 1.*vE^16))*(-1.859514170346336*^-9 + x))
```

Sidenote: the function should indicate a probability, and is the integral of a probability density defined in [0,x_max], therefore it should hold $f(0,vE)=1$ for any $vE$

Comment: Please provide copy & paste-able code (InputForm) so that we have something to work with.

Comment: you are right, done!

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use exact numbers like

```
x = 1/100; Table[
Rationalize[((E^(33972.7745398073*vE^2 + 1140.0906489396789*x)*
            (1.2345687547022132*^-23 + 
      vE^6*(4.087595291558347*^-13 - 0.00021982060458281043*
                      x) + 
      vE^2*(4.1941725957388944*^-19 - 
         2.255520642231904*^-10*x) + 
               
      vE^4*(-2.430661779483706*^-15 + 
         1.3071488339510708*^-6*x) + 
               
      vE^8*(-1.744191593358305*^-11 + 0.00937982415607754*x) - 
               6.639200573944934*^-15*x) + 
   E^(33972.774539807324*vE^2 + 1140.0906489396789*x)*
            (-3.270159894926998*^-23 + 
      1.7586098278121368*^-14*x) + 
          
   E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*(2.0355980730229598*^-23 - 
      1.0946949062266079*^-14*x + 
               7.569314750088174*^-12*x^2 - 
      1.4721183020268512*^-9*x^3 + 
               8.30796052725145*^-9*x^4 - 
      1.1896770509204967*^-8*x^5) + 
          
   E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2 + 
       1140.0906489396789*x)*(-1.6264357714319357*^-39 + 
               
      vE^14*(2.0083576467270298*^-14 - 
         0.000010800442818636717*x) + 
               
      vE^8*(2.571855800860126*^-21 - 1.383079431108135*^-12*x) + 
               
      vE^6*(1.7552515711539956*^-25 - 
         9.439301937812491*^-17*x) + 
               
      vE^2*(2.9153325110971034*^-34 - 1.5677925759254207*^-25*x) + 
               
      vE^4*(-2.6616831008553027*^-30 + 
         1.4313862961095703*^-21*x) + 
               
      vE^10*(-9.608099299823222*^-19 + 5.166994397269747*^-10*x) + 
               
      vE^12*(-4.953132878537244*^-15 + 
         2.663670413232032*^-6*x) + 
               
      vE^16*(-1.8595141703463354*^-9 + 0.9999999999999998*x) + 
               1.2253923290809874*^-30*x - 
      1.1383704954727588*^-27*x^2 + 
               2.592004365421134*^-25*x^3 + 
      6.875632678803749*^-22*x^4 + 
               3.830505707541381*^-19*x^5 + 
      5.720218174055417*^-21*x^6 - 
               4.6259292692714846*^-18*x^7 - 
      1.2371349122599874*^-16*x^8) + 
          
   E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*(-2.0355980730229598*^-23 + 
      1.0946949062266079*^-14*
                 x - 7.569314750088174*^-12*x^2 + 
      1.4721183020268512*^-9*x^3 - 
               8.30796052725145*^-9*x^4 + 
      1.1896770509204967*^-8*x^5 + 
               
      E^(1140.0906489396789*x)*(2.0355911402247853*^-23 - 
         3.3591048468065713*^-37*
                      vE^8 - 1.0946897704176435*^-14*x + 
         1.1383704954727588*^-27*x^2 - 
                    2.592004365421134*^-25*x^3 - 
         6.875632678803749*^-22*x^4 - 
                    3.830505707541381*^-19*x^5 - 
         5.720218174055417*^-21*x^6 + 
                    4.6259292692714846*^-18*x^7 + 
         1.2371349122599874*^-16*x^8))*
            HeavisideTheta[1.859514170346336*^-9 - x])*
 HeavisideTheta[
         
  1.859514170346336*^-9 + 29.79830996018*vE^2 - 
   x])/(E^(1140.0906489396789*x)*
       (1.758609827812137*^-14*E^(33972.774539807324*vE^2) + 
   E^(33972.7745398073*vE^2)*
            (-6.639200573944936*^-15 - 
      2.2555206422319046*^-10*vE^2 + 
               1.3071488339510708*^-6*vE^4 - 
      0.00021982060458281048*vE^6 + 
               0.009379824156077542*vE^8) + 
   E^(67945.54907961463*vE^2)*
            (-1.0946897704176435*^-14 - 
      1.567792575925421*^-25*vE^2 + 
               1.4313862961095709*^-21*vE^4 - 
      9.439301937812495*^-17*vE^6 - 
               1.3830794311081354*^-12*vE^8 + 
      5.166994397269748*^-10*vE^10 + 
               2.6636704132320325*^-6*vE^12 - 
      0.000010800442818636719*vE^14 + 1.*vE^16))*
       (-1.859514170346336*^-9 + x)), 10^(-100)], {vE, 1/100, 
14/100, 1/100}]
(* {0, 430648/6879181385, 698481/9203324930, 1805038/23785891251, 
3126065/41297181986, 
1576001/21651692414, 
313326/7428814151, -(450748/2278033113), -(4060782/2406568931), 
-(1242769/132435345), -(99750955/2239724446), -(49680141/
241024459), 
-(50095271/31604284), 66016483/33048707} *)
```

Then your expression seems to evaluate .

Edit: If you change the parameter of Rationalize to 10^-500 then
your sidenote appears to hold.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I see, however, negative numbers in your result. The result should be, as I anticipated, a probability between 0 and 1. Maybe there is a problem with the coefficients of the function itself, and the function really turns a bit negative?

Comment: Another strange thing: If I run 
x = 1/1000; Table[
 Rationalize[FD1[x, vE]["WD_O", 1], 10^(-500)], {vE, 10/100, 14/100, 
  1/100}]
Clear[x];
only the first result is not zero (FD1[x, vE]["WD_O", 1] is the function I gave), but if I run
FD1[x, vE]["WD_O", 1]//Inputform
and copy/paste the output to substitute FD1[x, vE]["WD_O", 1] in the code before I get nonzero results for all entries

Comment: Maybe machine precision of the coefficients is not enough. try to obtain them as exact numbers right away from your integration

Comment: There is something I still don-t get, if I run

FD1[1/1000, 14/100]["WD_O", 1]

I get 0, while if I run

FD1[x, vE]["WD_O", 1] /. x -> 1/1000 /. vE -> 14/100

I get 1.85